# youtube-ios-player-helper not showing iOS like video player controls

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I am using https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper to play videos from youtube in my app.
I am also using different playvars to control what to and what not to show on the player. But the controls section I see on the player is not like iOS.

[image]

I tried in other sample app where I could get the proper controls.

[image]

```
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
                                 @"playsinline" : @1,
                                 @"showinfo":@0,
                                 @"autohide":@1,
                                 @"modestbranding":@1
                                 };
[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:self.videoId playerVars:playerVars];
```

I played with few other options with these vars but no luck. I am not sure what controls what type of controls are displayed from apps perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracked down the issue. It was the custom user agent I was setting for my app, which was causing youtube player to behave differently.

Comment: When you remove user agent did it display with buttons? The controls / buttons also doesn't show on my side.

Comment: Yes, after removing custom user agent, I could see proper controls.